# "In an intervention on"

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, phrasal-verbs

Is the following sentence correct: "The debate was heated, but **in an interesting intervention on the topic** of climate change, professor X uniquely explained that ..."

I think the bolded part is correct, but I am not sure, how would you judge it incorrect?

Comment: I am not going to answer this because I am unsure what is intended by the word “intervention.” Does it mean “interruption” by someone who was not an invited debater? Does it mean “diversion” from the ostensible topic of the debate? It may be correct or incorrect, but it is obscure (at least without greater context).

Comment: Ok, it means a figurative intervention: he asked for the microphone, and asked to add an explanation of something the speakers might have missed.

Comment: Why are you not sure, what causes your doubt.  Here is a very similar use "this article offers a personal intervention on the topic of diversity and reimagining anthropology," https://www.teachinganthropology.org/ojs/index.php/teach_anth/article/view/594 or (slightly different context) "The current study was developed to assess the potential effectiveness of a simple educational intervention on the topic of basic hygiene (including water and sanitation), delivered in rural Rwanda."

Comment: OK. There is nothing incorrect about “intervention,” but the sentence is difficult to understand. It sounds as though what you are trying to say is something like “In the midst of this heated debate, Professor X was allowed to intervene with some clarifying remarks on climate change.

Comment: No, I am intending "allowed", through his won volition!

Comment: @JamesK I have an interesting question: how did find the similar use? I tried Googling but couldn't find as easily.

Comment: I googled ["intervention on the topic"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22intervention+on+the+topic%22&oq=%22intervention+on+the+topic%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30j0i390l4.683j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)  with quote marks

Comment: However, my question stands. What causes your doubt?

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't have doubted if I was writing to myself. I am writing a paper to be reviewed by an admissions committee, and I was doubtful for no reason, I knew it sounded correct, but couldn't adventure. You know, sometimes, that s called Anxiety!